# Unlink app from brew cask

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have an application, and it's listed in installed applications and when checking for upgrade. I don't want brew cask to handle this application. Is there a way to unlink it from brew without uninstalling and then reinstalling again manually?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no command in Homebrew Cask to forget an app.

However, there is a manual method: just delete the folder of the application you want to forget from `/usr/local/Caskroom` (Intel) or `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom` (ARM).